# Change object-property-value in Scheme

Tags: list, object, scheme

I have been dealing many days with a problem without any success. In my programm I define a list, let's call it "L", by shifting a single geometrical object, a circle, many times. So L is composed by manu circles. The object circle is also a list which contains its properties: center (center . #V), (height . H), radius (radius . R), and so on. So, the property radius is a pair in the 3rd position of the list circle. If I do (object-property-value circle 'radius) = R. Now, what I want to do is to create a new list, L-disorder, composed by circles with the same positions of those of L but each with different (random) radius. Then, I try this:

```
(define L-disorder (map
                     (lambda(obj) 
                      (set-cdr! (list-ref obj 3) (random:normal))
                     obj)
                     L))
```

My problem is that it changes the radius of all the circles the same way! And I want a different (random) value for all of them.

I would really thank any help or advise!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create new list, you shouldn't use mutation functons (set-cdr!).
`(map )` functions do all the magic for you: it iterates over source list, and creates new list.

```
 (define L-disorder 
   (map (lambda (circle)
      ; here we creating new circle
      (list (car circle) (cadr circle) (random:normal)))
    L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer Paul! I've tried and it works, but then I get a new circle as ((center . #V), (height . H), random number)) instead of the old ((center . #V), (height . H), (Radius . R)). I will see how to deal with. Thanks again!

Comment: Take a look on (random:normal) function. It should evaluates into (Radius . R).
Anyway, it's better to use construction functions, like
(circle v h r) which evaluates to circle

Comment: I got it. That was extraordinary!! Thanks a lot!